# create css with php laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

i need create get css files with laraven in my controller, because i have one problem my return result is one normal file (text file) and not a css file

my routes.php file contain:

```
Route::get('/css/{css}.css', 'FileController@GetCss')
->where('css','[A-Za-z]+');
```

FileController.php:

```
<?php

class FileController extends \BaseController {

    public function GetCss($css)
    {
        $file = File::get(app_path()."\css\\".$css.".css");
        return $file;
    }

}
```

and my css.css file contain:

```
body
{
    background: #f00;
}
```

browser return is:

```
body{   background: #f00;   }
```

and source (inspect element / ctrl+u):

```
body
{
    background: #f00;
}
```

what I must do to work as a css file?

Comment: I don't understand the question or what you are trying to do.

Comment: clarify it please, I thought you do all the CSS styling in the public folder?

Comment: This isn't what laravel is for

Comment: i need use php code in css file (body{background:<?= $color ?>}) so it is equal in public or not, need to generate the file anyway with php

Answer (score 0):

Your question need more clarification, I guess you are trying to build a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) or something like that.

When you say "what I must do to work as a css file?", I think you need to specify a header for the response:

```
public function GetCss($css)
{
    $file = File::get(app_path()."\css\\".$css.".css");
    $response = Response::make($file);
    $response->header('Content-Type', "text/css");
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: is +/- this, but with this i can't execute php code in my css file and i need execute

Comment: i test this and use css.php with php code `public function GetCss($css) { $file = File::get(app_path()."\css\\".$css.".php"); $response = Response::make($file); $response->header('Content-Type', "text/css"); return $response; }` but dont work